# C++ looping until a specific character is entered

Tags: c++, loops, for-loop, syntax

A practice exercise from the book I'm using (recapping the chapter on various kinds of loops) instructed me to create a program that continually asks the user to input single characters. There are two specifications:

1. The program should terminate when the "$" character is entered.
2. The program should keep a tally of the number of periods entered, and output the total as the program terminates. Basically, the whole idea is loop the input prompt -> count periods -> display this count and then terminate the program when "$" is entered.

Here's the code I have:

```
// Takes character input, tallies periods, stops on dollar sign

#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {

    char i; // input received
    int j = 0; // counter for # of periods

    cout << "This program will accept single-character entries and report the number of periods you've entered.\n";

    for (;;) {
        do {
            cout << "Please enter a single character, using $ to stop: ";
            cin >> i;

            if(i == '.')
                j++;
        } while(i != '$');

    if(i == '$')
        cout << "Total number of periods entered is " << j << " .";
        break;

    }
    return 0;
}
```

The program works fine and the code looks efficient to me, please correct me if I'm wrong. What seems strange to me is the use of the infinite for{} loop around the majority of the code. The chapter used this once or twice so it's the only way I currently know of to make a loop function in this manner.

Perhaps it's just my inexperience with the language, but **is the use of a loop with `(;;)` here a typical occurrence in C++?** The syntax of having a loop with no parameters defined seems to make sense for what I needed to do, but the whole for(;;){} block still looks strange to me.

Comment: The `for(;;)` loop is irrelevant in this situation,the loop with at least one condition i.e `for(;some condition;)` will still make sense but not here.

Comment: Thanks, I took that loop out and everything still works correctly. The book had used a for(;;) loop to demonstrate the same function (looping until specific input) earlier in the chapter so that's where I got the idea. I'm not on the computer with that code at the moment, so I'll take another look tomorrow.

Is the for(;;) loop as I had it, with no conditions, useful in any way or is it extraneous as it was here?

Comment: In this particular case the for loop is doing nothing, since the break jumps out of it before it ever loops. But in general there are certainly times when such a "forever" loop is needed, with either a break or a return within it. It is probably more common to do this with a while(true){...} loop.

Comment: @ScottMcP-MVP yes absolutely right, that could have been an answer along with some details. that's why I said irrelevant in this situation, there are some situation where this loop is necessary.

Comment: @ScottMcP-MVP Thanks, it seemed like a strange use of the for{} loop to me.

Comment: There are a few ways to make an infinite loop, some people prefer `while (1)` or `while (true)`. I personally prefer `for (;;)`. And no, it's not uncommon.

Comment: What made you think you needed the for loop? Read your code again, you have a "while (!condition)" immediately followed by an "if (condition)". Ask yourself: How would you reach the "if" without the condition being true? If that's the case, whey do you need the "for()"? Some C programmers use `for(;;) { if (...) break; work; if (...) break; more work; break; }` as a flow control paradigm that is never intended to loop. It is, infact, a goto, and probably shouldn't be used in "C++". Only use "for(;;)" when you intend to loop.

Comment: @kfsone That's true, upon rereading it I can see that the "while" and "if" conditions cover everything by themselves. The reason I included for(;;) is that the book had used it when introducing the concept of a loop that executes until a specific user entry, and therefore figured it was the standard approach. I didn't attempt running the program without the for(;;), but I'll keep this in mind for the future.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No need for either the outer loop or the `if` check after the inner loop.

I would also check for errors or EOF when reading, and so would code it something like this:

```
int periods;
char ch;

std::cout << "Please enter a single character, using $ to stop: ";
for (periods = 0; std::cin >> ch && ch != '$'; )
{
    if (ch == '.')
        periods++;
    std::cout << "Please enter a single character, using $ to stop: ";
}

std::cout << "Total number of periods entered is " << periods << " .";
```

Comment: That looks like a much more concise way to do it. I haven't come across using input as part of the loop conditions yet, but the line

`for (periods = 0; std::cin >> ch && ch != '$'; )`

is simply declaring the variable, accepting the input (as opposed to my dedicating a whole line to `cin`) and then checking that it's not a dollar sign, correct? It looks as though it's shrinking my code down to one all-inclusive block.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg you could probably improve this answer, the question was: *is the use of a loop with `(;;)` here a typical occurrence in C++?*

Comment: @TaylorFlores I bolded the question as per your edit, that should make it clearer.

Answer (score 1):

The use of `for (;;)` or others like `while (1)` I have seen almost exclusively in books or example snippets of code . While I've never seen this in full-fledged programs, it is  probably just a little less common. Usually, though, there's at least one expression (sometimes more) within the loop. Although it's possible to use `breaks` only, it takes away from readability. Consider the following:

```
for (;;){
    // do some stuff here
    if (anexpression) break;
}
```

And

```
do {
    // do some stuff here
} while (anexpression);
```

Which one is more readable? I'd prefer the latter, but it's still just an opinion. There are also many other ways to write a loop (ie):

```
evaluateinput:

if (anexpression) goto evaluateinput;
```

Comment: Note that the `break` in the original question is not controlled by an `if`.

Answer (score 1):

Forever loops is more common on electronics. Sometimes main even look like this:

```
void main()
{
    Init();
    while (1);
}
```

In this case main function waits for interrupts to handle.

Usually we don't use forever loops but it's not a bad decision, just not standart way to solve problem.

Lets say code which looks:

```
while (1)
{
...
    if (condition)
        break;
}
```

We can change into:

```
while (!condition)
{
...
}
```

In cases when we need to run loop at least once we can use do-while loop.